# Create Loop for MySQL insert and Update From a 4 input form

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form with 26 items and 3 sub items that I need to insert into my database, I wonder if there's a way to loop the queries to aboid habing a long list of queries like this.

```
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $suc=$_GET['sucursal'];
    $columnas="client_key,sucursal,extra,op1,op2,op3";

    # Inicia inserción de valores de Opciones ...

    #1
    if(empty($_GET['x1'])){ /* nada que ver */ }else{
    if(empty($_GET['op11'])){ $op1='NULL'; }else{ $op1='1'; }
    if(empty($_GET['op21'])){ $op2='NULL'; }else{ $op2='1'; }
    if(empty($_GET['op31'])){ $op3='NULL'; }else{ $op3='1'; }
    if(empty($edit)){
    $extas=mysqli_query($cnx,"INSERT INTO xtr_opt ($columnas)VALUES('$key','$suc','".$_GET['x1']."','$op1','$op2','$op3')")or die($cnx);
    }else{
    $extas=mysqli_query($cnx,"UPDATE xtr_opt SET client_key='$key',sucursal='$suc','extra=".$_GET['x1']."',op1='$op1',op2='$op2',op3='$op3')")or die($cnx);}}
    #2
    if(empty($_GET['x2'])){ /* nada que ver */ }else{
    if(empty($_GET['op12'])){ $op1='NULL'; }else{ $op1='1'; }
    if(empty($_GET['op22'])){ $op2='NULL'; }else{ $op2='1'; }
    if(empty($_GET['op32'])){ $op3='NULL'; }else{ $op3='1'; }
    if(empty($edit)){
    $extas=mysqli_query($cnx,"INSERT INTO xtr_opt ($columnas)VALUES('$key','$suc','".$_GET['x2']."','$op1','$op2','$op3')")or die($cnx);
    }else{
    $extas=mysqli_query($cnx,"UPDATE xtr_opt SET client_key='$key',sucursal='$suc','extra=".$_GET['x2']."',op1='$op1',op2='$op2',op3='$op3')")or die($cnx);}}
    #3
    if(empty($_GET['x3'])){ /* nada que ver */ }else{
    if(empty($_GET['op13'])){ $op1='NULL'; }else{ $op1='1'; }
    if(empty($_GET['op23'])){ $op2='NULL'; }else{ $op2='1'; }
    if(empty($_GET['op33'])){ $op3='NULL'; }else{ $op3='1'; }
    if(empty($edit)){
    $extas=mysqli_query($cnx,"INSERT INTO xtr_opt ($columnas)VALUES('$key','$suc','".$_GET['x3']."','$op1','$op2','$op3')")or die($cnx);
    }else{
    $extas=mysqli_query($cnx,"UPDATE xtr_opt SET client_key='$key',sucursal='$suc','extra=".$_GET['x3']."',op1='$op1',op2='$op2',op3='$op3')")or die($cnx);}}
    #4
    if(empty($_GET['x4'])){ /* nada que ver */ }else{
    if(empty($_GET['op14'])){ $op1='NULL'; }else{ $op1='1'; }
    if(empty($_GET['op24'])){ $op2='NULL'; }else{ $op2='1'; }
    if(empty($_GET['op34'])){ $op3='NULL'; }else{ $op3='1'; }
    if(empty($edit)){
    $extas=mysqli_query($cnx,"INSERT INTO xtr_opt ($columnas)VALUES('$key','$suc','".$_GET['x4']."','$op1','$op2','$op3')")or die($cnx);
    }else{
    $extas=mysqli_query($cnx,"UPDATE xtr_opt SET client_key='$key',sucursal='$suc','extra=".$_GET['x4']."',op1='$op1',op2='$op2',op3='$op3')")or die($cnx);}}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using arrays, like `name=x[]` and `name="op1[]"`? Then you could write a simple `foreach()` loop in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agreed with the answer of @Barmar related to NULL value and wrong update statement. Here I'm also suggesting another approach to achieve the same functionality,

```
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    $suc = $_GET['sucursal'];
    $columnas = "client_key,sucursal,extra,op1,op2,op3";

    $arrMain = array(1=>'x1',2=>'x2',3=>'x3',4=>'x4');
    $addQueryValues = "";

    foreach ($arrMain as $key=>$mainVal)
    {
        if(!empty($_GET[$mainVal]))
        {
            $op1 = empty($_GET['op1'.$key])?'NULL':1;
            $op2 = empty($_GET['op2'.$key])?'NULL':1;
            $op3 = empty($_GET['op3'.$key])?'NULL':1;
            if (empty($edit))
            {
                $addQueryValues[] = "('$key','$suc','" . $_GET[$mainVal] . "','$op1','$op2','$op3')";
            }
            else
            {
                $extas = mysqli_query($cnx, "UPDATE xtr_opt SET client_key='$key',sucursal='$suc','extra=" . $_GET[$mainVal] . "',op1='$op1',op2='$op2',op3='$op3')")or die($cnx); // Missing where clause
            }
        }
    }
// Following code will execute all insert statement in to one query
    $allValues = implode(",", $addQueryValues);
    $addQuery = "INSERT INTO xtr_opt ($columnas) VALUES ".$allValues;
    $extas = mysqli_query($cnx, $addQuery) or die($cnx);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop and concatenate the index into the input names.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    if(empty($_GET["x$i"])){ /* nada que ver */ }else{
        if(empty($_GET["op1$i"])){ $op1='NULL'; }else{ $op1='1'; }
        if(empty($_GET["op2$i"])){ $op2='NULL'; }else{ $op2='1'; }
        if(empty($_GET["op3$i"])){ $op3='NULL'; }else{ $op3='1'; }
        if(empty($edit)){
            $extas=mysqli_prepare($cnx,"INSERT INTO xtr_opt ($columnas)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")or die($cnx);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($extas, "ssisss", $key, $suc, $_GET["x$i"], $op1, $op2, $op3);
        }else{
            $extas=mysqli_prepare($cnx,"UPDATE xtr_opt SET client_key=?, sucursal=?,'extra=?,op1=?,op2=?,op3=?")or die($cnx);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($extas, "ssisss", $key, $suc, $_GET["x$i"], $op1, $op2, $op3);
        }
        mysqli_stmt_execute($extas);
    }
}
```

I've also shown how to use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection.

And be aware that your code puts the literal string `'NULL'` into the table, not a SQL `NULL` value. If you want a real null, remove the quotes around `NULL`.

Your `UPDATE` statements are also missing a `WHERE` clause, so each of them is going to update *every* row in the table. You probably need to fix that. In fact, I suspect you can combine the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements into a single `INSERT` statement using the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option.

Comment: This is awesome, I love it. I only had to remove  closing parentesi  after the op3.
You are great!